# Powershell Recursively List or Delete Files older than 30 days include all files in folders in the subtree regardless of when the folder was modified

Tags: powershell, file, recursion

I am using powershell to delete files in folders that are last modified older than 30 days. (LastWriteTime).
My script works if the files are in the path specified but not if they are in a subfolder of that root path. It seems the folder has been considered in the script and I am at a loss as to why.
I get one file returned out of 2000 files that were created, modified, accessed 4 months ago.

My folder structure is: P:\Root/SubFolderRoot/SubFolder1/SubFolder1 ..-.. SubFolder9
There are multiple subs and any of them can contain files older than 30 days.. I am only interested in the files older than 30 days regardless of the Folder Modified, Accessed, Created Times. I have searched on stack and can provide several almost exact code examples to mine but they do not work.

```
$folderTree = 'P:\Root\SubFolderRoot'
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderTree -File -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } 
    | foreach-object { Write-Host  $_.FullName }

# Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } 
# Select-Object FullName
```

Comment: In which sense you code you have there does not work ? Please be clear, we can't see your screen. the condition `-not $_.PSIsContainer` is not needed in your code but aside from that the code looks fine.

Comment: Also, I would do `$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date` to have that date at midnight

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon when I was just running a select it listed files in particular folders and did not care about the folder lastwritetime but the files only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$folderTree = 'P:\Root\SubFolderRoot'
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderTree -Filter * -File -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } |
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Should do what you want.
Using the `-WhatIf` switch will cause the code to not delete anything, just output in the console what *would* happen.
Once you are satisfied the correct files are listed, take off the `-WhatIf` switch and run again.

Comment: I think I found the issue, I am using LastWriteTime. I am guessing that our company antivirus and scanning must be modifying that value. To check this 'hypothesis' I need to list files with their LastWriteTime. I will mark your response as answer .